# Errors In Bumblebee

Tags: bumblebee

I recently installed bumblebee.My problem is when I ran any command in terminal it showed me an error.If I run following commands in terminal

bumblebeed --driver DRIVER 
bumblebeed --group GROUP
bumblebeed  --pidfile FILE

it shows me following errors

[  904.901313] [ERROR]Module 'DRIVER' is not found.
[ 2656.497095] [ERROR]Cannot open or write pidfile /var/run/bumblebeed.pid.
[ 2729.466978] [ERROR]Could not set the GID of bumblebee: Operation not permitted

respectively.
How can I fix this or do I have to reinstall bumblebee?

Comment: did you place `sudo` before the command

Comment: Yes.But,It didn't work.Still getting the same error.

Comment: what are the commands didi you use to install bumblebee.Did your laptop is an optimus laptop?

Comment: try to reinstall it,if error comes post me.

Comment: Yes.I think mine one is a optimus laptop.Because I tested it as directed in github.

Comment: try to reintall it

Comment: This time I don't want to waste my 70 MB of data.So please,tell me the recommended commands to install bumblebee.

Comment: My laptop model is Lenovo Ideapad Z580 with intel i5 processor @2.50GHZ boost upto 3.10,nvidia GT630M Geforce cuda.4GB ram.

Comment: Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
linux-headers-generic is already the newest version.
bumblebee is already the newest version.
bumblebee-nvidia is already the newest version.
primus is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.                                                                  I think was not reinstalled.

Comment: Now do ihave to reboot?

Comment: yes,you have to reboot.

Comment: still getting errors.I ran. bumblebeed --driver DRIVER.the error is same."[ERROR]Module 'DRIVER' is not found"except the number before the "[ERROR]Module 'DRIVER' is not found "which is[138.633709].

Answer (score 0):

Run the below commands to install bumblebee:

`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:bumblebee/stable`
`sudo apt-get update`

`sudo apt-get -f install bumblebee bumblebee-nvidia virtualgl linux-headers-generic`

`-f` to fix the missing packages.

For ubuntu 13.10 replace last command by this

`sudo apt-get install bumblebee bumblebee-nvidia primus linux-headers-generic`

Don't forget to reboot after running all these commands.

Comment: still getting errors.I ran. bumblebeed --driver DRIVER.the error is same."[ERROR]Module 'DRIVER' is not found"except the number before the "[ERROR]Module 'DRIVER' is not found "which is[138.633709].

Comment: did you follow all the instructions on http://askubuntu.com/questions/36930/how-well-do-laptops-with-nvidia-optimus-work.

Comment: No.I shall try tomorrow.Thanks for your help,Sir.